# French characters in Email Java not displaying properly

Tags: java, email

I am using Java to send a mail including `mail.jar`. I have french characters in subject of the mail. They are not displaying properly.

`Subject: Identifiants à l'école`

I am getting response as `"Identifiants &#x00E0; l'&#x00E9;cole"`.

Code:

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
message.setSubject(MimeUtility.encodeText(pSubject));
message.setContent(pBody, "text/html ; charset=utf-8");
```

Note: Host is smtp

Please help me in solving this issue.

Thanks